# How to enable hot swapping in debug mode with gradle and jetty?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, gradle

I'm using jettyRun for running my simple spring application. I wanted to enable hot swapping with Intellij debuger, but looks like jetty doesn't catch the changes.
On http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Gradle+Jetty+Plugin I seen that it should work with:

```
jettyRun.scanIntervalSeconds=1
```

On the other hand, there is some inconsistency. On the gradle homepage this parameter is not listed: http://www.gradle.org/jetty_plugin. Anyway, is there any way to enable this on gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, actually found it myself now.

Looks like this parameter is not needed at all. Hot deploy works anyway.

I just wasn't able to seen that because my vaadin application was keeping session even after F5. To restart it properly it's enough to add *?debug&restartApplication* to the application url.

So, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> in IntelliJ + <kbd>F5</kbd> in the browser (with *?debug&restartApplication*) works fine ;)

Comment: To be exact, only the ?restartApplication is needed if you don't want to see the debug window.