# Gradle + IntelliJ: HotSwap in a plain Java application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, hotswap

For a plain Java/Swing application, I am currently migrating the ant buildscripts to a gradle build.

While I got it up and running quickly, **changes in recompiled classes are no longer picked up while debugging** in IntelliJ IDEA.

All my build/run actions are [delegated to gradle](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ch/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html).

**Things I've considered:**

- This is not a duplicate of [How to enable hot swapping in debug mode with gradle and jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282568/how-to-enable-hot-swapping-in-debug-mode-with-gradle-and-jetty), I'm working with a standalone Java application, not Spring
- For the same reason, https://github.com/thomas-adriano/gradle-hot-swap does not apply, I think
- I would expect the HotSwap mechanism to detect changes in `/build/classes/` regardless of the used build tools
- I added the `idea` [plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) to my build.gradle, hoping it would fix any potential confusions of classpaths
- When using the built-in IntelliJ-Compiler, hotswapping works as expected

So I put together this [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate my problem:

**build.gradle:**

```
group 'hotswaptest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

**src/main/java/HotSwappingOrNot.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class HotSwappingOrNot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame asdf = new JFrame();
        asdf.setContentPane(new JLabel("asdf"));

        asdf.setVisible(true);

        asdf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                float r = (float) Math.random();
                Color c = new Color(r, 1-r, r);
                asdf.setBackground(c);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In order to test hotswapping, I change the `new Color(r, 1-r, r)` -bit to `new Color(r, r, r)` and press `Ctrl+Shift+F9`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet fixed [IDEA-163187](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163187).
I'm not aware of any workarounds available so far :(

Comment: OK, I think I get it now -- I simply may have started out with wrong assumptions about how people combine external build tools with IDEs. Now I switched back to the built-in compiler for debug builds and only use gradle to pull dependencies and build releases.

Comment: supposed to be fixed in upcoming IJ-2019.1

Comment: Did you figured out how to do this?

Comment: fixed in 2019.1